# How to get query parameters in a rest controller in a GET request?

Tags: java, controller, spring-boot, restful-url

This should probably be a one-liner, but I am not used to Spring or SpringBoot, and so I'm having troubles.

I am building a RESTful service, with query parameters. For example: `http://myweatherapi.com:8080/foo?zip=14325&prop=humidity`.

I am trying a SpringBoot's template within which I have this controller:

```
@RestController
public class ServiceController {

    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceController.class);

    @RequestMapping("/foo")
    public String foo(@QueryParam("foo") String foo) {
        requestContextDataService.addNamedParam("foo", foo);

        // how can I access the full URL/query params here?

        return "Service is alive!!";
    }

}
```

My question is: *how can I access the full URL/query parameters*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public String foo(HttpServletRequest request,@QueryParam("foo") String foo) {
    requestContextDataService.addNamedParam("foo", foo);

    // how can I access the full URL/query params here?
    request.getRequestURL() 
    request.getQueryString() 

    return "Service is alive!!";
}
```